# A Guess Turing Machine that accepts a random Binary number

Tags: turing-machines

I'm trying to construct a turing machine that accepts any random binary numbers. From the theory (and partial example) in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQnPM6sydkk&t=630s), I understand (correctly?) that this is something that is more easily doable with a Non deterministic turing machine.

So I have come up with a concept as such that I start with state Q1 (from the left side of the band) and upon reading a zero I move right, and upon reading a One 1 move right and the machine enters the same state, again and again until the complete word is read.

I understand that this is a way I can accept an input. What I dont understand is how to include accept and reject states on the machine? I would appreciate all help on the matter.

Comment: What do you mean by "accepts any random binary numbers"?  Please define precisely the set of numbers it should accept. Random probably isn't the right word here.

Answer (score 2):

There can't be "random numbers", each number is exactly that one, not at all "random". You can talk about getting a number at random from a set, perhaps according to some distribution. You might talk about a stream of bits, each of which is selected at random. But then the sequence 010101... is perfectly possible as an outcome (if it can't appear, it isn't random!).